# Gitolite delete hook

Tags: gitolite

I'm trying to delete a Gitolite repository with a trigger (hook) since Gitolite forces this cleanup on the admin.

The $GL_REPO variable is necessary, but would I know the repo is being deleted ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a hook.
You can use **[commands](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cust.html#commands)** (with the latest 3.x gitolite).

Those commands include the [command '`D`'](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/commands/D)

```
ssh git@host D unlock repo
ssh git@host D rm repo
```

And your repo is gone.

Note that ([commit b9bbb7](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/b9bbb78278c12d9468d8c50b61ca27e6d6fa0c5b)):

> you can completely disable the '`rm`' command by setting an rc variable
>   (meaning in the `.gitolite.rc` file)

```
#   called D_DISABLE_RM to "1".
```